# Dynamically generated list of checkboxes in Tkinter only returns 0s

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I am writing a small gui with Tkinter in python 2,7. At some point I call a function that creates a popup window that is populated by a number of checkboxes, the number of checkboxes is defined by the attributes variable.

```
def attribute_select(attributes):
popup = tk.Tk()
popup.wm_title("Attribute selection")
label = ttk.Label(popup, text="Please select which of the following \n attributes will undergo k-anonymity.",
                  font=NORMAL_FONT)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

def read_status(key):
    var_obj = var.get(key)
    print "key is:", key
    print "var_obj.get() is:", var_obj.get()

def leave_mini():
    popup.destroy()

var = dict()
count = 1
for child in range(attributes):
    var[child] = tk.IntVar()
    chk = tk.Checkbutton(popup, text='Attribute: '+str(count), variable=var[child], justify="left", onvalue=1,
                          offvalue=0, command=lambda key=child: read_status(key))
    count += 1
    chk.pack()
print var
exit_button = ttk.Button(popup, text="OK", command=leave_mini)
exit_button.pack()
popup.mainloop()
```

Everything runs just fine but when I try to check one of the boxes the variable value doesn't change the printout every time is: [ key is: 0 var_obj.get() is: 0 ] or [ key is: 5 var_obj.get() is: 0 ]. So the key is proper for every box but the variable doesn't change. I'm sure it's a simple fix I just can't see it... any ideas?

Comment: do you use other tkinter windows in program ? It should be only one `mainloop()` and only one `tk.Tk()` - for subwindows use `tk.Toplevel()`.

Comment: The code as posted will not run.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you furas this is my first time with tkinter and the mainloop issue did not cross my mind at all.

Answer (score 0):

You must not create more than one instance of `Tk`. By creating an instance in `attribute_select` I must assume you've create the "real" root window somewhere else. One of the side effects of creating more than one instance of `Tk` is that your tkinter variables (`IntVar`, etc) don't behave the way you expect them to.

If you need popup windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for problems in the dictionary and variables and the multiple Tk instances issue flew completely over my head.